# Flattening a 2D array to a 1D array based on indexes

Tags: java, array

I am certain there is a better way to flatten the array with an optimized approach for the solution.

Example:

> [[1,2,24],[12,1241,122],[3,2],[7]] => 1 12 3 7 2 1241 2 24 122

---

```
public class flattenArray {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int inputLists[][] = {{1,2,24},{12,1241,122},{3,2},{7}};

    flattenList(inputLists);

}

public static void flattenList(int input[][]){
    List result = new ArrayList();
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> elements = new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<input[i].length;j++){

            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();


            if(elements.get(j)!=null) {
                temp=elements.get(j);
                temp.add(input[i][j]);
                elements.put(j, temp);
            }

            else {
                temp.add(input[i][j]);
                elements.put(j,temp);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        if(elements.get(i)!=null)
        result.addAll(elements.get(i));
    }

    for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
        System.out.println(result.get(i)+" ");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use raw types:

```
List result = new ArrayList();
```

Should be:

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you are using Java8, you could simplify the code of the map creation using the function `computeIfAbsent`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++){
        elements.computeIfAbsent(j, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(input[i][j]);
    }
}
```

In the next loop, you are using the break condition incorrectly.

```
for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){ // input.length is not what you need 
    if(elements.get(i)!=null)
        result.addAll(elements.get(i));
}
```

`input.length` is the number of arrays in your 2d array. If the length of any array is greater than the number of arrays, the code is skipping values.

This is a failed test:

```
Input: {{1,2,24},{12,1241,122}} 
Output: 1 12 2 1241
Expected: 1 12 2 1241 24 122
```

You don't need to use `input` in the loop, you have a map with all the elements for each index, so you can make the conversion using only the map:

```
// Use a TreeMap instead of a HashMap to have the elements ordered by index
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> elements = new TreeMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
...
for (List<Integer> e : elements.values()) {
    result.addAll(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. That is a good catch. for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){ // input.length is not what you need 
    if(elements.get(i)!=null)
        result.addAll(elements.get(i));
}        would it be best to hold the max key in the HashMap and run up to that value and spit out the values in the next list

Answer (score 5):

#### Separate concerns

You shouldn't output in the same method that generates the results.

> ```
>     for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
>         System.out.println(result.get(i)+" ");
>     }
> ```

You don't need to use an index variable here.

```
    for (int element : flattenArrays(inputArrays)) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
```

I also removed the `+ " "`, as it doesn't really do anything if you print a new line each time.

I moved this into `main` and changed `flattenArrays` to return a `List`.  I changed `flattenLists` to `flattenArrays` as being more descriptive.  And changed `inputLists` to `inputArrays` to match.

Now you can choose to display the results.  Or you can manipulate them further.  It's your choice.  Before you would have had to rewrite the method in order to do something other than display or even just to make a display change.  Now you can leave the method untouched and choose how and what to display in the caller.

#### Don't waste objects

> ```
>             List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
>
>
>             if(elements.get(j)!=null) {
>                 temp=elements.get(j);
>                 temp.add(input[i][j]);
>                 elements.put(j, temp);
>             }
>
>             else {
>                 temp.add(input[i][j]);
>                 elements.put(j,temp);
>             }
> ```

You create a new `ArrayList` on every iteration, but you only use it occasionally.  Why not simplify things?

```
            List<Integer> temp = elements.get(j);
            if (temp == null) {
                temp = new ArrayList<>();
                elements.put(j, temp);
            }

            temp.add(input[i][j]);
```

You don't have to `put` into the `Map` things on which you previously did a `get`.  They're already in the `Map`.  This is because you have a reference to that `List`.  So you are modifying the `List` already in the `Map`.

So instead of having two paths, we have one path.  We just need to ensure that there is already a `List` in the `Map` for `j`.  If not, then we need to create one and put it in the `Map`.  Again, we can do this before we modify the `List`, as we still have the reference to it after we put it in the `Map`.

We only call `get` once this way, regardless of path.

But why use a `Map` or other intermediate data structure at all?

#### Don't overcomplicate things

```
    public static List<Integer> flattenArrays(int input[][]) {
        List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();

        int previousSize;
        int column = 0;
        do {
            previousSize = results.size();

            for (int[] row : input) {
                if (row.length > column) {
                    results.add(row[column]);
                }
            }

            column++;
        } while (previousSize != results.size());

        return results;
    }
```

This copies the data directly, without any intermediate variables.  It does so at the cost of checking each array for as many elements as the longest array has.

I changed `result` to `results`, as it is a `List` and can have multiple values (or none).

It would be possible to use `Arrays.asList(input)` with the [iterator remove method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/223929/6660678) to pop out the finished arrays.

```
    public static List<Integer> flattenArrays(int input[][]) {
        List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();
        List<int[]> data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input));

        for (int column = 0; !data.isEmpty(); column++) {
            Iterator<int[]> it = data.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                int[] row = it.next();
                if (row.length > column) {
                    results.add(row[column]);
                } else {
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
```

I'll leave it up to you if the savings in comparisons is worth the increased overhead of the extra data structure.

I would find either of these easier to follow than the `Map` method.

Answer (score 4):

You can transpose the array and then flat it. This approach to me seems more intuitive than putting elements on a map.

However transpose needs to be implemented with the particularity to support jagged arrays. In order to make an implementation you might need to make some assumptions.

I made an assumption that `row(i).length >= row(j).length`, where `i < j`

```
public static int[][] transpose(int[][] values){
    int[][] transposed = new int[values[0].length][];

    int minLastLenIdx = values.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < values[0].length; ++i)
    {
        while(values[minLastLenIdx].length < i + 1){
            minLastLenIdx--;
        }

        transposed[i] = new int[minLastLenIdx + 1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++)
        {
            transposed[j][i] = values[i][j];
        }
    }
    return transposed;
}

public static int[] flattenList(int input[][]){
    return Arrays.stream(transpose(input))
                 .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
                 .toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify your flattening algorithm when you determine the maximum length of the sub arrays with a helper function first:

```
public static int maxLength(int array[][]) {
    int maxLength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        maxLength = array[i].length > maxLength ? array[i].length : maxLength;
    }

    return maxLength;
}
```

Now you can iterate over the jagged array `maxLength` times and by checking if the current iteration index exceeds the current sub array length you know whether you can safely read a value from a sub array or not:

```
public static void flattenList(int input[][]) {
    int maxLength = maxLength(input);
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
            if (i < input[j].length) {
                result.add(input[j][i]);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
        System.out.print(result.get(i)+" ");
    }
}
```

See this working example: https://ideone.com/EV8Wjg

...or this one: http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/568038

(Boy, it's hard to find a decent online compiler for Java.)

Comment: [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php) works really good. That approach is also a good one.